# Readfile image not working on PHP

Tags: php, image, header, content-type, readfile

I have the below PHP code to load image

```
header('Content-Type: image/'.$contentFormat);
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($image));
readfile($image);
```

When I request the url in console I get the bellow header response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 28 Nov 2014 13:13:59 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 107885
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=30
Server: Apache/2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=617a3a6eba912178f810f10cc5d171f3; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 0


ÿØÿà
```

including `ÿØÿà`,

What could be the problem? I searched all my php files for whitespace. Any guess or suggestions where I can search for the whitespace

Comment: What does `$image` print by using `var_dump($image);`?

Comment: my relative path, and It works fine on my local server (editted)

Comment: This is either a problem of wrong filepath, either a permission problem.

Comment: var_dump($image); gives
string(35) "public/images/main_logo.jpg"

Comment: It was working fine till the end of yesterday :'(

Comment: You said above `my absolute path`, and that is `relative path`. Read about them first.

Comment: Sorry about that, I commented before I execute that